# Conversion from std::string to unsigned char[]

Tags: c++, string, hex

Let's suppose I have a string str which consists of characters default to hexadecimal system (0-9, a-f):

```
string str="1234567890abcdef";
```

I also have an empty array of n-length (n is known):

```
unsigned char arr[n]
```

What I would like to do is fill my array arr with values of str but in a specific manner shown below:

```
unsigned char arr[8] = {0x12U, 0x34U, 0x56U, 0x78U, 0x90U, 0xabU, 0xcdU, 0xefU};
```

As it is presented the string str was divided into smaller hexadecimal chars. How can I achieve it? The algorithm for seperation is simple, but I can't figure out how to change string to unsigned char and how to add 0x at the beginning and U at the end of the chars.

Comment: What end result are you trying to achieve here? Is this an interface to a library?

Comment: I'm confused by the statement that you want to "add 0x at the beginning". Are you trying to fill `arr[]` from `str` at runtime, or convert one form to the other in your source?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing hexadecimal values from a std::string in a std::vector and vise versa?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843369/storing-hexadecimal-values-from-a-stdstring-in-a-stdvector-and-vise-versa)

Comment: @Andy: Mayby I was not clear enough, sorry. By "add 0x at the beginning" I meant convert one form (str) to other in my source code (hex).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are somewhat unclear. Does the following program perform the action you desire?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>


void str2bin(const std::string& in, unsigned char out[])
{

    const char* data = in.data();
    const std::string::size_type size = in.size();
    for(std::string::size_type i = 0; i < size; i+= 2) {
        unsigned int tmp;
        std::sscanf(data+i, "%02X", &tmp);
        out[i/2] = tmp;
    }
}

int main() {
    unsigned char arr[8];
    str2bin("1234567890abcdef", arr);
    std::cout << std::hex;
    std::copy(arr, arr+8, std::ostream_iterator<unsigned int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`0x12U` is acually an `unsigned int`, not a `char`. It just happens to fit in a char. Most importantly, it's a literal that's only used by the compiler. Once in memory, numbers all become binary - series of bits.

In this case, you have a string that contains hexadecimal numbers. I.e. each char represents just 4 bits. You'll need to parse that. a simple function would be `sscanf`. The format specifier `%2X` reads two hex characters and stores them in a single int. Therefore, you could use `"%2X%2X%2X%2X%2X%2X%2X%2X"` to read 8 integers, and then copy each of them to the corresponding `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider the [delimited list builder](http://jsprenkle.reddawn.net/?p=19) pattern if you need a less specific version.